# List not rendering to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a Todo app using react+redux. When I add new todo in my list, state of store and state of TodoList component are updated successfully but My todoList code not working properly. React component is not rendering list.

Structure of state is below.

```
State = [
   {
     id,
     text,
     completed
   },...
]
```

My code is below.

**Todo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
import Filter from './Filter';

class ToDo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Todo App</h2>
                <Form />
                <TodoList />
                <Filter />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDo;
```

**TodoList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { toggleToDo } from '../actions';

class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this);
        const todolist = this.state.list;
        return (
            <ul>
            {
                todolist.map(function(listValue) {
                    return <li>{listValue.text}</li>;
                })
            }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('TodoList state',state);
    return {
        todos: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({toggleToDo},dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: I don't see you using your todos from props inside a todolist component. For a component to rerender it's state should update

Comment: Why you try to store data in state of TodoList. You have already data in redux store. And secondly you should have const todolist = this.props.todos (todos from map state to props).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping your state to props with `mapStateToProps` so you should get this state value from your props.

`const { todos } = this.props;` and iterate on `todos` instead of `todolist`.